# how to remove specific portion of data frame to remove in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have read text file convert to dataframe tables using scala spark.
I still have this issue:

The table looks like this:

```
 +------------+----------+----+----+
    |value       |col1      |col2|col3|
    +------------+----------+----+----+
    |FIRST:      |FIRST:    |null|null|
    |erewwetrt=1 |erewwetrt |1   |null|
    |wrtertret=2 |wrtertret |2   |null|
    |ertertert=3 |ertertert |3   |null|
    |;           |;         |null|null|
    |FIRST:      |FIRST:    |null|null|
    |asdafdfd=1  |asdafdfd  |1   |null|
    |adadfadf=2  |adadfadf  |2   |null|
    |adfdafdf=3  |adfdafdf  |3   |null|
    |;           |;         |null|null|
    |SECOND:     |SECOND:   |null|null|
    |adfsfsdfgg=1|adfsfsdfgg|1   |null|
    |sdfsdfdfg=2 |sdfsdfdfg |2   |null|
    |sdfsdgsdg=3 |sdfsdgsdg |3   |null|
    |;           |;         |null|null|
```

So, final dataframe table looks as,(needs to contains only FIRST portion...)

```
+------------+----------+----+----+
 |value       |col1      |col2|col3|
 +------------+----------+----+----+
 |FIRST:      |FIRST:    |null|null|
 |erewwetrt=1 |erewwetrt |1   |null|
 |wrtertret=2 |wrtertret |2   |null|
 |ertertert=3 |ertertert |3   |null|
 |;           |;         |null|null|
 |FIRST:      |FIRST:    |null|null|
 |asdafdfd=1  |asdafdfd  |1   |null|
 |adadfadf=2  |adadfadf  |2   |null|
 |adfdafdf=3  |adfdafdf  |3   |null|
 |;           |;         |null|null|
 ...
```

My problem is, how can I remove the rows from SECOND to `;`.

How can achieve it in scala spark?

Comment: I think I understand what you ask for (probably it would help if you added a new non-`Second` block at the end; it seems the answerers misunderstood). I do not think this can be easily done as it requires to keep state while visiting all rows, which is not supported by the DataFrame API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my quick and dirty solution: (see updated solution below)

```
//Lets define a sample DF (just like your DF)
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(("First",1),("First",2),("dummy",3),("Second",4))).toDF
//Get the index of the row where "second" occurs
val idx = df.rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(x=> x._1(0) == "Second").map(x=> x._2).first
//filter
val res = df.rdd.zipWithIndex.filter(x=> x._2 < idx).map(x=> x._1)
//and the result:
res.collect
//Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([First,1], [First,2], [dummy,3])
```

Oh yes if you want to convert it back to DF, do this:

```
val df_res = spark.createDataFrame(res,df.schema)
```

**UPDATED SOLUTION:**
Based on additional inputs, I am updating my answer as below:
(My assumption is that "Second:....." occurs only once in the file. If it doesnt, you should by now get an idea how to work it through anyway)

```
//new df for illustration
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(("First:",1),(";",2),("dummy",3),(";",4),("Second:",5),("some value",5), (";",6),("First:",7),(";",8) )).toDF
//zip wit index
val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
//this looks like:
rdd.collect
//res: Array[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, Long)] = Array(([First,1],0), ([;,2],1), ([dummy,3],2), ([;,4],3), ([Second,5],4), ([some value,5],5), ([;,6],6), ([First,7],7), ([;,8],8))
// find the relevant index locations for "second" and ";"
val idx_second:Long = rdd.filter(x=> x._1(0) == "Second:").map(x=> x._2).first
val idx_semic:Long = rdd.filter(x=> x._1(0) == ";").filter(x=> x._2 >= idx_second).map(x=> x._2).first
// and here is the result
val result = rdd.filter(x=> (x._2 < idx_second) || (x._2 >idx_semic))
// verify the result
rdd.collect
// res: Array[(org.apache.spark.sql.Row, Long)] = Array(([First,1],0), ([;,2],1), ([dummy,3],2), ([;,4],3), ([First,7],6), ([;,8],7))
```

Comment: Hi, I tried...but problem is mine is large file and it have number of times FIRST: elements occurred... If the elements more that 3 how can I parse it (remove SECOND: to ;) where ever it occurs in the column...just consider my columns derived from a text file with ,FIRST:
val1=1
val2=2
val3=3
;
FIRST:
val1=1
val2=2
val3=3
;
SECOND:
val1=1
val2=2
val3=3
;
FIRST:
val1=1
val2=2
val3=3
;       This FIRST is repeated in that large text file and need to retrive only FIRST: elements...thank you

Comment: I understand your problem better now. Could you also throw some light whether "SECOND:......;" can occur more than once in your file?

Answer (score 0):

Creating dataframe as mentioned by @datamannz

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array(("First",1),("First",2),("dummy",3),("Second",4))).toDF("value", "col1")

df.filter(col("value").notEqual("Second")).show
+-----+----+
|value|col1|
+-----+----+
|First|   1|
|First|   2|
|dummy|   3|
+-----+----+
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for the reply...df.filter(col("value").notEqual("Second")).show only remove the value SECOND: ,but its contents displayes. I need to remove from SECOND: to ";" end delimiter of this. I have one text file and that text file have large occurrence of FIRST:...I only need to parse FIRST: and its elements(between FIRST: and ;) and convert to dataframe... My problem is not able to remove that SEOND: and its follwing elements..Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows,
file.filter(col(x).notEqual(y)).aggregate()

Comment: If that is your solution then why is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47609170/14267427) marked as the solution?